# Recursion issue with tic-tac-toe minimax

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use minimax but it's getting stuck, can anyone shed some light? The method is `computerBestMove` above the body of HTML stuff.

When I put in a bugger it leads to stack too deep.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>

    <style>
      #game_board {
        border-style: solid
      }
      th {
        border-style: inset;
        font-size: 20px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
      }
    </style>

    <script>
      var gameOver = false;
      var state = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
      var human = false
      var computer = true
      var humanValue = -1;
      var compValue = 1;
      var winCombo = [
        [0,1,2],
        [3,4,5],
        [6,7,8],
        [0,3,6],
        [1,4,7],
        [2,5,8],
        [0,4,8],
        [2,4,6]
      ]
      var squares = document.getElementsByClassName("square");


      function markSquare(square) {
        if(gameOver === false ) {
          for(var x = 0; x < 9; x++ ) {
            if(squares[x] == square && state[x] == 0) {
              set(x, humanValue);
              computerMove();
            }
          }
        } else {
          console.log("game is over");
        }
      }

      function set(index, player) {
        if(player == humanValue) {
          squares[index].innerText = humanValue;
          state[index] = humanValue;
        } else {
          squares[index].innerText = compValue;
          state[index] = compValue;
        }
      }

      function checkWinner(board, player) {
        var value = player === human ? humanValue : compValue;
        //8 differnt way of winning
        winCombo.forEach(function(combo) {
          if (value === state[combo[0]] &&
            state[combo[0]] === state[combo[1]] &&
            state[combo[1]] === state[combo[2]]) {
              gameOver = true;
              console.log(value + " wins!");
            }
        })
        return gameOver;
        // for(var x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        //   var win = true;
        //   for(var y = 0; y < 3; y++){
        //     if(board[winCombo[x][y]] != value) {
        //       win = false;
        //       break;
        //     }
        //   }
        //   if(win) {
        //     return true;
        //   }
        // }
        // return false;
      }

      function returnWinner() {
        var winner = null;
        winCombo.forEach(function(combo) {
          if (state[combo[0]] === state[combo[1]] && state[combo[1]] === state[combo[2]]) {
            (combo[0] === -1 ) ?  (winner = "player") : (winner = "computer");
          }
        })
        return winner;
      }

      function noMoreMove(board) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
          if (board[i] === 0) {
            return false;
          } else
          return true;
        }
      }

      function computerMove() {
        computerBestMove(state, 0, computer)
      }

      function computerBestMove(board, depth, player) {
        //if player wins ... = -10

        if(checkWinner(board, !player) === true) {
          return -10 + depth;
        }else if(noMoreMove(board) === true) {
          return 0;
        }

        var value = player === human ? humanValue : compValue;
        var max = -Infinity;
        var index = 0;

        for(var i = 0; i < 9; i++){
          if(board[i] === 0) {
            var newBoard = board.slice();
            newBoard[i] = value;

            var moveValue = -computerBestMove(newBoard, depth+1, !player);

            if(moveValue > max) {
              max = moveValue;
              index = i;
            }
          }
        }
        if(depth === 0){
          set(index, computer)
        }
        return max
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p id="message">A the message area.</p>

    <button type="button" name = "choice" value = "two players" checked>Two players </button>
    <button type="button" name = "choice" value = "vs AI">Unbeatable AI </button>

    <table id='game_board'>
      <tr>
        <th id="square0" class = 'square' onclick="markSquare(this);"></th>
        <th id="square1" class = 'square' onclick="markSquare(this);"></th>
        <th id="square2" class = 'square' onclick="markSquare(this);"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th id="square3" class = 'square' onclick="markSquare(this);"></th>
        <th id="square4" class = 'square' onclick="markSquare(this);"></th>
        <th id="square5" class = 'square' onclick="markSquare(this);"></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th id="square6" class = 'square' onclick="markSquare(this);"></th>
        <th id="square7" class = 'square' onclick="markSquare(this);"></th>
        <th id="square8" class = 'square' onclick="markSquare(this);"></th>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code is not correct. If you return from a function, the loop automatically stops. So this will only check the first cell each time.
Once you replace it with a proper loop that checks all cells, then you get a stack overflow as you say.

```
  function noMoreMove(board) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
      if (board[i] === 0) {
        return false;
      } else
      return true;
    }
  }
```

The stack overflow issue is caused by this line of code:

```
var moveValue = -computerBestMove(newBoard, depth+1, !player);
```

This is just incorrect logic. The only time computerBestMove() doesn't create a infinite loop, is when either a player has won, which is impossible the first 3 moves. Or when there are no more empty cells, which after fixing the noMoreMove function also never happens the first 8 moves. Both are checked at the start.

So you're always triggering this infinite loop.

You have to rewrite the `computerBestMove()` function so that the parts that check which move is best and the part that gives the result are split. You want to loop checking for the best position, but that loop has to stop once all combos have been checked.